# My thread got commandeered, and "subquestions"

Tags: support, users, spam

Hey -- I've had great success with my questions on StackOverflow, and a couple days ago, I made a good first question on ServerFault here:
[Buying an old laser printer -- what will need to be replaced?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139043/buying-an-old-laser-printer-what-will-need-to-be-replaced)

I got a great answer from the user *joeqwerty* who is an expert in the field of my question.  But unfortunately, the comments section in his post got flooded with **spammy nonsense from other users**.

After further research, I now have a new "subquestion," I think it makes sense to ask *joeqwerty* specifically.

**So my questions:**

1. Will this spammy (or "hammy") nonsense get removed, or is that sort of thing tolerated on Serverfault?
2. Is there a good way to add a kind of "subquestion" to my original question in a way that will make it once again noticed by other users, by bumping it up the front page or notifying those users that already replied?
3. Is there a way to contact a specific user individually, so I can ask *joeqwerty* a question?  Do I just need more reputation to do that?

Answer (score 3):

> Will this spammy (or "hammy") nonsense
>   get removed, or is that sort of thing
>   tolerated on Serverfault?

Maybe, maybe not. You can always return to the original discussion and ignore the chat that's taking place there and all will be fine.

> Is there a good way to add a kind of
>   "subquestion" to my original question
>   in a way that will make it once again
>   noticed by other users, by bumping it
>   up the front page or notifying those
>   users that already replied?

I suggest you just open a new question.

> Is there a way to contact a specific
>   user individually, so I can ask
>   joeqwerty a question? Do I just need
>   more reputation to do that?

No.

Comment: I would also add that if you open a new question, link to the preceding (related) question for context.

Comment: No, you cannot contact a specific user individually *on the site*, but he may have included contact info on his user profile. I would hope that most users are okay with being emailed if they included their address.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged the comments as spam. You can do likewise. Hopefully a mod will wander along and swat.

Comment: Huh, I did also but ran out of comment votes. Apparently I only get 5 on Server Fault; is it reputation-based?

Comment: According to the FAQ, it's 5 flags and 30 votes, so that would explain it.

Comment: I seem to have been the lucky sixth vote on most of those comments, as they vanished before my eyes.

Comment: Now the comments make no sense